# how do you style Text children in React Native with styled components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

so if I have this

```
const MyView = styled.View`
    background: green;
    color: red;
`
```

and I have

```
<MyView>
  <Text> Hello </Text>
</MyView>
```

the text is not red

so I tried

```
const MyView = styled.View`
    background: green;
    & > Text { color: red; }
`
```

you can do this with normal styled-components in React, however the text is still not red

how do I achieve this?

I know I can do

```
const StyledText = styled.Text`
    color: red;
`
```

and then

```
    <MyView>
      <StyledText> Hello </StyledText>
    </MyView>
```

but I want to avoid this if I can. is it possible to access Text child elements in RN?

Comment: Yes as Bartraz Says not possible like CSS on the web - rather annoying but it is watit is

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately styled-components for RN is just a wrapper that return a common RN View (or Text) with style prop `<View style={...styles} />`. There is no way to styling children in the parent block.

Answer (score 1):

Like Batraz Jioty mentioned in his answer, I don't think it's possible. Style inheritance in RN is very limited. I believe you could achieve something like that only putting one  inside another, but from a View I don't think it's possible

Answer (score 0):

As said, CSS like style override is not possible in react native.
However, **there is a pattern that allow to style children** but that doesn't involve styled lib:

```
function TextRed({ children }) {
  return React.cloneElement(children, {style: { color: 'red' }})
}
```

This is the only way I know, it can be very useful in some cases!