# How style child element from parent in react native styled-components

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I have container with child

```
  <Container>
  {[1, 2, 3].map((el) => {
    return (
      <Container2 key={el}>
        <Text>{el}</Text>
      </Container2>
    )
  })}
</Container>
```

and when I trying style child with help of selector it doesn't work for me.

```
const Container = styled(Block)`
  flex-direction: column;
  & > * {
    background: black;
    flex: initial;
    margin-right: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    border-bottom-color: white;
  }
`
```

As I understood selectors don't work in native, but how we can style child from parent
in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible

See: [how do you style Text children in React Native with styled components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353506/how-do-you-style-text-children-in-react-native-with-styled-components)

You can just create a stylesheet and add a class for those children components, then add the `style` tag to it, like so:

```
<Container2 key={el} style={styles.yourCreatedClass}>
    <Text>{el}</Text>
  </Container2>
```